# Tool to create boilerplate module on python (similar to `bundle gem ...` in Ruby)

Tags: python, ruby, bundler, project-structure

Currently, I'm working to port some software from Ruby to Python.

On Ruby to create a new gem you usually use `bundle gem ...` to generate a new gem project structure.

Is there a similar tool in Python world?

Comment: Maybe https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/1.7.2/

Comment: Pip is the python equivalent to bundler. http://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages.html. Why they can't package it in a proper executable is beyond me though.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks a lot for suggestion, if you will write an answer I will accept it